# ember.js - how to load custom route template?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In my code below I am trying to load the 'home' route template as my index route?

how do I do this?      go to mysite.com  then the home route template must load only?

I don't want to see the application template and use its {{outlet}}.

Thanks for your help

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function(){

    this.resource('home', {path: ''} );
    //this.resource('home', {path: '/h'} );
    this.resource('about', {path: '/a'} );
    this.resource('contact', {path: '/c'} );
});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function() {
        this.transitionTo('contact'); 
    }
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function() {
   this.transitionTo('home'); 
  }
});

App.HomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

});

App.AboutRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

});

App.ContactRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

});
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ember Starter Kit</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.1.2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-1.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/attempt1.js"></script>


<script type="text/x-handlebars">
   <div>
     page - Application
   </div>

   {{outlet}}
 </script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="home">
  <div>
    page - Home
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="about">
  <div>
    page - About
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="contact">
  <div>
    page - Contact
  </div>
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

---

Comment: I was checking my answers and I see that you haven't followed up. Did you fix the problem?

Comment: Hi no I havnt found the solution yet, thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

change id for data-template-name :

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="home">
  <div>
    page - Home
  </div>
</script>
```